# links in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I'm experimenting with codeigniter but don't really understand how links work.

for example, I have a link like this:

localhost/ci/welcome/cat/7

My base url is localhost/ci, so by clicking on this link I would expect the method "cat" of controller "welcome" to be called.

This method is very simple:

```
   function cat()
    { 
        echo "just a test.";
    }
```

Pretty basic - I would expect to see the text on screen, but I just see a 404 -page not found error.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3):

http://localhost/ci/index.php/welcome/cat/7

Answer (score 2):

Have you configured `mod_rewrite` (or URL rewriting in general) properly for CodeIgniter? It's not supported out of the box.

They have some instructions in their [wiki](http://codeigniter.com/wiki/mod_rewrite/).

Comment: I have this htaccess file:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|captcha|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

I've copied it from the book I'm using to learn codeigniter, so I'm not entirely sure what it does. 

Do you think it's ok?

Comment: PS don't know if it makes any difference, but I'm using MAMP

Comment: Kind of a "delayed reply", but have you enabled mod_rewrite for Apache? You have to edit httpd.conf to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I had problems with the rewrite rule suggested in the user guide.  I was also getting 404s.  I had to remove the slash before index.php in the rule.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

As Veeti says, also remember to enable mod_rewrite for Apache.

Comment: Removed the slash but still doesn't work.
I've checked the file httpd.conf (in mamp/conf/apache) and it contains this: LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

so I think the module is loaded correctly?

I've tried with a few different links, and noticed that 
localhost/ci/welcome/test opens a google 404 ("oops! this link appears to be broken)
while localhost/ci/index.php/welcome/test opens a codeigniter 404.

Don't know whether this makes a difference?

Comment: When you go to localhost/ci/index.php/welcome do you see the CodeIgniter welcome page?